# Posting file contents to Issue with Github scripts

Tags: github-actions

According to [Github scripts docs](https://github.com/actions/github-script#comment-on-an-issue), I can post to a Github issue like,

```
jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

I want to post a body that reads data from a file. I tried,

```
body: fs.readFileSync('/my/cool/file')
```

but it complains that `fs` does not exist.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Install the `fs` module and use `require('fs')` before using the `fs` module.

> `require` A proxy wrapper around the normal Node.js `require` to enable requiring relative paths (relative to the current working directory) and requiring npm packages installed in the current working directory

[source](https://github.com/actions/github-script#readme)

```
jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: npm install fs
    - uses: actions/github-script@v3
      with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            const fs = require('fs')
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: fs.readFileSync('/my/cool/file')
            })
```